# Find range of a rational function

Tags: functions

Find range of a function: $f(x)=\dfrac{2|x|-1}{|x|+1}$. I tried to graph this function and I have got an answer: $y\in\{0\}\cup[\dfrac{1}{2};2]$, but it's incorrect. Note that you can't use calculus.

Answer (score 1):

You want the values of $y$ such that $\frac{2\lvert x\rvert-1}{\lvert x\rvert+1}=y$ has some solution in $x$. This is a parametric equation which may be solved as such $$\frac{(2-y)\lvert x\rvert-(1+y)}{\lvert x\rvert+1}=0\\ (2-y)\lvert x\rvert-(1+y)=0$$

There is no solution for $y=2$, whereas for $y\ne2$ we may proceed $$\begin{cases}y\ne2\\ \lvert x\rvert=\frac{1+y}{2-y}\end{cases}$$

which has solutions in $x$ if and only if $\frac{1+y}{2-y}\ge 0$. This is the case if and only if $-1\le y<2$.

Putting all together, the range is $[-1,2)$.

Answer (score 0):

$ f $ is defined at $ \Bbb R $ by

$$f(x)=\frac{2(|x|+1)-3}{|x|+1}=2-\frac{3}{|x|+1}$$

If $x\ge 0$, then

$$f(x)=2-\frac{3}{x+1}$$
$f$ is continuous and strictly increasing from $ [0,+\infty) $ to $$[f(0),\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x))=[-1,2)$$

If $ x\le 0$, then
$$f(x)=2+\frac{3}{x-1}$$
$ f $ is continuous and decreasing from $ (-\infty,0] $ to $$[f(0),\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x))=[-1,2)$$

thus, the range is
$$f(\Bbb R^-)\cup f(\Bbb R^+)=[-1,2)$$

Answer (score 0):

You might want to double-check that graph of yours:

[image]

Based on this, the answer is evidently $[-1,2)$. How can we conclude this?

- The function is continuous over the reals, since the denominator is never $0$.
- A minimum is achieved at $x=0$, yielding precisely $f(x)=-1$, also justifying a closed bracket.
- For $x$ positive and increasing, $f(x)$ is monotonic increasing as well. How might we conclude this? Borrowing from Jose Carlos Santos' answer, a simplification can happen:
  $$\frac{2|x|-1}{|x|+1} = \frac{2|x|-1+3-3}{|x|+1} = \frac{2|x|+2-3}{|x|+1} = \frac{2(|x|+1)}{|x|+1} - \frac{3}{|x|+1|} = 2 - \frac{3}{|x|+1}$$
  and, clearly, as $x$ increases, the right term goes to zero. A similar argument gives monotonic decreasing on $(-\infty,0)$.
- The function is bounded above by $2$, which it can clearly never reach.

Thus, by the intermediate value theorem, per its continuity, $f$ maps to every element in $[-1,2)$.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I graphed it with myself not with software because we aren't allowed to use it. So I think it's where I have got a mistake